# Do I have to match the manufacturer of the PCIe card with the manufacturer of motherboard?

Tags: pci-express

Is it possible to purchase another brand of PCIe card and slot in the PCIe slot on the existed motherboard?  Will it function properly? What is the downside?  Isn't PCIe slot a standard protocol?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[PCIe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express) is indeed an industry standard protocol.  As long as the card fits, it should work.

Furthermore a PCIe card with fewer lanes should work in a slot that offers more lanes.

[image: PCIe connector]

P.S. Minor detail: A PCIe connector may be physically of the x16 size but could have fewer electrical connections, depending on the board. (i.e. it could electrically be an x4 or x8 slot; in this case an x16 card would fit but would run at x4 or x8 speed.) On some motherboards the number of lanes in a slot can be changed by jumpers and/or settings in the firmware (as in the case of crossfire/SLI boards).

Answer (score 2):

Its a standard protocol. There's no downside. This was also true of its predessors all the way back to  <strike>the time of the dinosaurs</strike>  the days of the Industry *standard* architecture.

Any PCIe card will fit and work correctly in a slot that's of the same physical and electrical configuration. Typically you could run a card in a slot with a higher number of channels (say x1 in x4 or x8 in x16), or a bigger physical slot (say a physical x1 in a x4 slot), but not always.

There's no downside to do with *mixing manufacturers*. While you could *rarely* build a system from one brand of parts, being able to take say, an asus motherboard, throwing in a gigabyte video card, and a creative sound card, and expecting everything to work is something that *should* happen. If something fails, its probably something other than using heterogeneously branded parts.